# How to get total number of clusters, jobs, libraries installed etc. in existing azure databricks workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-databricks

Is there a programmatic way to  get total number of clusters, jobs, spark & scala runtime versions, libraries installed , other artifacts etc. in existing azure databricks workspace?

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving number of cluster, jobs, runtime versions, libraries etc. you can use databricks API.
For example [cluster API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters) for information about cluster.

Access to this API can be authenticated [by databricks personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication).